# Changing one textline into multiple textlines

Tags: sed

I am trying to split this line into multiple lines, each containing a separate sentence:

```
This is a first sentence. This is a second sentence. Look at this: a third sentence! Where does this ends? I have no Idea, who knows…
```

We have to use the shortest command that is possible.

I tried this :

```
sed 's/[.?!]/&\n/g'
```

But it adds one single space after every new sentence :

```
This is a first sentence.
 This is a second sentence.
 Look at this: a third sentence!
 Where does this ends? I have no Idea, who knows…
```

Keep in mind that we have to keep the line as short as possible

Comment: `sed 's/\([.!?]\)  */\1\n/g'`, and if you're guaranteed single-space-separated sentences you can dump a ` *` from that.

Comment: Your attempt hasn't added any spaces, they were already there in the first place!

Answer (score 2):

Try with GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/([.?!]+) */\1\n/g' file
```

With regular sed:

```
sed 's/\([.?!]\{1,\}\) */\1\
/g' file
```

These test for one or more occurrences of sentence terminators followed by 0 or more spaces..

Comment: Simply adding the "()" helped me out! Thx a lot 
sed -r 's/([.?!]) /&\n/g' file

Comment: @user3657270 That would leave extra spaces at the end of the lines. If that is not important you can leave out the `()` too, since `&` does not use them :
`sed -r 's/[.?!] */&\n/g' file`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
sed 's/[.?!]/&\n/g' file | sed 's/^ //g'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`

```
awk '{gsub(/\. /,"."RS);gsub(/\? /,"?"RS);gsub(/\! /,"!"RS)}1' file
THis is a first sentence.
This is a second sentence.
Look at this: a third sentence!
Where does this ends?
I have no Idea, who knows.
```

---

Or this: (it adds a space at end of the line)

```
awk '{gsub(/[.!?] /,"&"RS)}1' file
THis is a first sentence.
This is a second sentence.
Look at this: a third sentence!
Where does this ends?
I have no Idea, who knows.
```